# remove element from hash map if key is empty

Tags: java, string, hashmap, key

how can I find an element of an HashMap in Java, if the HashMap is of the form  and one key is empty, so it only contains a blank character.

In my example:

Let wordMap be an instance of HashMap filled with elements.

```
if (wordMap.containsKey("")) {
  wordMap.remove("");
}
```

This didn´t work. I hope someone can help me.

After I did this, I convert the hash map to a tree map and sort it by the biggest Integer. I print that to the console and this is what I get with

```
System.out.println("results: " + tree)
```

I get on the console:

```
results: { =194, in=73, ...}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure ? This works perfectly : http://ideone.com/YmpIyC

Comment: *"one key is empty, so it only contains a blank character."* -- What do you mean by this?

Comment: This worked for me. Actually you don't really need to check with `containsKey()` as `remove()`  just returns null if the key does not exist

Comment: It will work for every human being using JAVA ;)

Comment: What did not worked for you ?

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. Can you post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You should explain in what way it 'didnt work'.  Threw an exception?  Removed the wrong pair from the hashmap?  Value of wordMap.keySet().size() did not change?

Comment: Java is a word and not an acronym, stop shouting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a couple of different things.  For your issue, I would do:

```
if (wordMap.containsKey(" ")) {
  wordMap.remove(" ");
}
```

However, to be more comprehensive I would iterate over the keys and remove any key that passes the `StringUtils.isEmpty()` test.

Comment: `if (wordMap.containsKey(" "))` is not necessary. Simply call `remove`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8,
then you can apply the following solution.

```
    wordMap.entrySet()
       .removeIf(e -> StringUtils.isBlank(e.getKey()));
```

Here `StringUtils.isBlank` can be replaced with custom logic to check for invalid keys.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to retrieve the value? If yes, then you need replace that 
  wordMap.remove("");
with 
  wordMap.get("");

Otherwise, if you're trying to remove the Entry with a key "" that is the correct way to do it.